# while VSbuild task getting error error MSB4057: The target "_IsProjectRestoreSupported" does not exist in the project.,

Tags: c#, .net, azure, msbuild, nuget

Working on wpf application, with Wix to create .msi. why am i getting error

> D:\a\1\s\wpfsetup\wpfsetup.wixproj : error MSB4057: The target
> "_IsProjectRestoreSupported" does not exist in the project

using msbuild version '17.2.1.25201
NuGet Version: 4.4.1.4656

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below steps help to fix the issue:

- As per my research, it seems to be many bug fixes in every alternate version of the MS Build like 15.8.1, 16.11, etc.
- There are some breaking changes and behavior changes mentioned in the [MSFT official documentation of MSBuild 17.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/whats-new-msbuild-17-0?view=vs-2022). Please check this documentation to know more information if these changes with their resolutions helps to fix the issue.
- And it might be the folder path in the build was wrong. Target Name must include the name of the solution folder. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596475).
- Try Restoring the `MSBuild Nuget Package Version` using this command:

```
nuget restore MySolution.sln -MSBuildVersion 16.11
```